# Select query selects same row twice

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on an ETL tool. Where I am selecting data in batches. Source and target tables have same structure:

| id(p_key) | name | created_at | dept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Data is selected from source table and inserted into target, pretty straight forward.

The issue is in select query. Everything works fine, when I use this query to select:

```
SELECT su.id, su.name, su.dept FROM source_user su LIMIT 5 OFFSET :offset*;
```

But when I change this query to below, it often selects same row twice.

```
SELECT su.id, su.name, su.dept FROM source_user su ORDER BY su.created_at ASC LIMIT 5 OFFSET :offset*;

* offset starts from 0 and increases by 5 everytime.
```

If a row is selected in first batch of 5, it gets selected in second batch of 5 too. So when we try to insert it in the target table, it gives `duplicate key value violates unique constraint` error.

Logic to increase offset is as below, and I do not think there is any issue with this:

```
int offset = 0;
selectOp(offset, limit);
insertOp();
offset += 5;
```

What could be the issue, why is the query selecting the same row in 2 batches?

Comment: mysql and postgresql are different databases.  Please pick ***one*** tag.

Comment: Not sure I get the problem, or maybe you didn't explain clearly.  A single SQL query can only return a given record in a table once (unless you are doing something like a union).

Comment: Do the affected rows have similar created_at? So that sorting might be a bit rando?

Comment: Yes there is an actual join operation, but both tables are in 1-1 mapping. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: LIMIT/OFFSET makes no sense until ORDER BY by an expression which provides rows uniqueness added.

Comment: @jared Does it really happen? I think that could be a reason. Can I do something to mitigate it?

Comment: You need stable ordering which you can achieve by adding other columns of your choice (that can uniquely identify the row) in `order by`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have multiple rows with the same `created_at` value.  If so, the order of the rows with the same `created_at` is arbitrary, and can be different each time you run the query.

To reliably paginate the data, each row should have an absolute and deterministic position.  This can be achieved by including a column that doesn't have duplicate values in it, such as the `id`.

```
SELECT su.id, su.name, su.dept
FROM source_user su
ORDER BY su.created_at ASC, su.id ASC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET :offset*;
```